# Twitter sign-in integration into existing website: merge accounts and storing twitter credentials

Tags: twitter, single-sign-on, twitter-oauth

I have a website with it's own login/registration mechanism (PHP, session, user and user_profile DB tables with username and password, etc). Let's call this the ABC account.

I just finished integrating Twitter's sign-on using Oauth, available as a "sign-on using twitter" button above my normal login form.

So now I have this scenario:

A user logs on via Twitter. Because Twitter, unlike Facebook, does not proivde access to a user's email address, I don't know if this person who logged in via Twitter is an existing user (in my user table) or not. So I create a new account for them (let's call this the "Twitter" account) and prompt them to merge with an existing "ABC" account by entering their "ABC" credentials. If they do so and everything matches, I store their twitter username, id and token in the DB record for their ABC account. Next time they login via Twitter I know who they are in terms of the ABC account (ie, the accounts are "merged") and all is good!

Except, I'd like to have the ability to have my site send tweets on their behalf, which basically means I need an authorized Twitter connection, which I only have if they logon via the Twitter button, not through the ABC account. The reason is with the latter I have their token_secret, received from the Twitter API callback after signing, but with the former I don't. My first thought of course was to save the token_secret in my DB (with the ABC account record) to remove this restriction, however it seems like this is the equivalent of a password and storing it could be secruity hole?

To boil this down to a question: is it "standard" practice to store the oauth token secret in the DB to achieve what I'm trying to do (which itself seems like a pretty standard function for a modern site)? . If not, what's an alternative implementation?

Update: looking at: [Best practices - store Twitter credentials or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879430/best-practices-store-twitter-credentials-or-not) it seems this is definitely *not* a 'best practice'. But it seems like what I'm trying to accomplish is...not sure how to implement? Maybe some kind of cookie-based solution??

Peter

ps -- BTW, if anyone has a better way to do the account "merge" I described I'd be open hearing about that as well. I did some google searching but really couldn't find anything too useful, although this problem must have been solved many times I imagine??? My understanding is that in the Facebook case the email can be used to "uniqely" identify a user (ie, match them to an ABC account), and do the merge without prompting (although I'm not even sure this is totally secure?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the tokens that Twitter gives you during the OAuth process is -exactly- how you should be doing it.  Shove them in the DB.

Comment: Thx. I like this solution because it's simple and it will work! My only concern is that their "secret" token is the equivalent of a password thus storing unencrypted would be a security hole (and to encrypt it would have to be 2-way).

Comment: I don't think it is a security hole as the secret token can only be used in conjunction with your applications oauth consumer and secret key.