# Twitter App with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices - store Twitter credentials or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879430/best-practices-store-twitter-credentials-or-not)

Am working on an a web app that has alot of twitter integration,and using Elliott Haulighin's twitter library for codeigniter.
Am new to to the twitter API, my app is supposed to able to update users twitter status but the dilemma am facing is storing the user's twitter authorization so they not have to reauthorize the my twitter app when they revisit the site.
I was wondering if its possible to store the authorizations on a database table

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879430/best-practices-store-twitter-credentials-or-not . Using [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) means you don't have to store passwords at all.

Answer (score 0):

On lines 39 and 40 of [Elliot's library test controller](https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-twitter/blob/master/application/controllers/tweet_test.php), he states that you can save the tokens in a database:

```
// These can be saved in a db alongside a user record
// if you already have your own auth system.
```